# how can we hide param in url of yii framework?

Tags: yii

Sorry I am new bie and I am working friendly url in Yii framework.The index page is ok but when I input param for edit, the url is not friendly.

index page: `http://localhost/news/news/index.html`

edit page: `http://localhost/news/news/edit/59.html`

how can we hide the id param and have url like this:

`http://localhost/news/news/edit.html`

here is the config in main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',    
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'urlSuffix'=>'.html',                   
            'rules'=>array(         
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

You will have to attach some form of an identifier to the url to denote a unique record. If you want to do away with the ID,use a title or text to achieve the purpose making urls SEO friendly. Incase you are going that route, you will have to set up a custom url rule .
Refer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes for more info.